# Using a constructor to put variables into an object throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays

Using this code

```
System.out.println("New Mark Entry\n--------------" + "\n\nEnter the description (up to 40 characters will be displayed):");
name = TextIO.getlnString();
if (name.length() > 40) {
    name = name.substring(0,40);
}
System.out.println("What was the assignment out of?");
totalMark = TextIO.getlnDouble();
System.out.println("What was the students mark?");
mark = TextIO.getlnDouble();
System.out.println("What was the weight of this assignement?");
weight = TextIO.getlnDouble();
input = 1;
int openSpot = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < markbook.length; i++) {
    if(markbook[i].getAssignment(name) == null) {   // java.lang.NullPointerException is thrown here
        openSpot = i;
        break;
    }

}
markbook[openSpot] = new Mark(name, totalMark, mark, weight);
break;
```

Causes a java.lang.NullPointerException to be thrown. Im a tad confused at what to do to fix this. If anyone could help or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreicated

Comment: Have you checked what's in `markbook[i]`?

Comment: A stacktrace usually helps.

Comment: Put breakpoint in this code..i.e. `name`,markbook[i] or like wise cases...

Comment: Have you initialized markbook[]?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)

Comment: markbook[i] doesn't exists

Comment: The program is incomplete. Provide the full description to link the code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are initializing markbook after and trying to use it before

```
for(int i = 0; i < markbook.length; i++) {
        if(markbook[i].getAssignment(name) == null) {   // java.lang.NullPointerException is thrown here
            openSpot = i;
            break;
        }

    }
    markbook[openSpot] = new Mark(name, totalMark, mark, weight);//you are initializing markbook after and trying to use it before
```

it should be like following

```
//initialize first
markbook[openSpot] = new Mark(name, totalMark, mark, weight);

//use later
for(int i = 0; i < markbook.length; i++) {
        if(markbook[i].getAssignment(name) == null) {   // java.lang.NullPointerException is thrown here
            openSpot = i;
            break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the NPE happens on that exact line, the most likely cause is that `markbook[i]` is `null`. You don't show how you've initialised it, but in addition to allocating the array you also need to create the elements.

For an example, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10044418/367273

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the line where the NullPointerException has been throw.

Let say it is

```
markbook[i].getAssignment(name)
```

Then I would check that I actually set markbook[i] to something, because otherwise it will be null.

Note: this is not enough.

```
MyType[] markbook = new MyType[4];
```

as this is the same as

```
MyType[] markbook = { null, null, null, null };
```

If it still doesn't make sense, I would use a debugger to debug your code.